Differences between Antifoundation (Aczel) and negated Foundation
I'm looking to construct a model for $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{AF}$ (Antifoundation/Aczel's axiom). (So please try avoiding any explicit mentioning of what such a model would/should be.) Previously I managed to construct a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathsf{Reg}$ by performing a so-called Bernays-Rieger permutation (given a model $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, I eliminated the pair $(\emptyset_M, \{\emptyset\}_M)$ from $\in_M$ and added the new pair $(\emptyset_M, \emptyset_M)$, hence "switching" the roles of "empty set" between $\emptyset_M$ and $\{\emptyset\}_M$ and making $\emptyset_M$ out to be the unique purely selfcontained set within the new model $\langle M, \in'_M \rangle$).
My question is: is this not enough also to qualify as a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{AF}$? (I know there's a $0.0001\%$ chance it is, but I can't seem to figure out why yet.)
As I seem to understand it, Aczel states the existence of a unique decoration for every graph (or is it every APG?) (Or more precisely: the existence of a unique decoration for everything the model at hand thinks is a graph, no?) Either way, when one thinks of nonwellfounded sets, there's usually three types: (1) the loop (i.e., the set $\Omega$ such that $x \in \Omega \Leftrightarrow x = \Omega$), (2) the circular chain (i.e., some sets $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with $x_i \in x_{(i \ \mathrm{mod} \ n)+1}$), and (3) the infinitely descending chain (i.e., sets $x_1, x_2, \dots$ with $x_i \in x_{i+1}$).
The thing is, if we speak of pure circular or infinitely descending chains, they all reduce to case (1) of the loop, no? What I mean by "pure" is that they contain no other sets (or atoms) besides those making the cycle/downward chain. Graphwise this just means that there are no extra "branches" coming off any of the nodes, i.e., it's always just a circle or just an infinite downward chain. In these cases are they not the "same" as $\Omega$? It's easy to see that $\Omega$ is a case of the two, but also if we have that $x_1 = \{x_2\}$, $x_2 = \{x_3\}$, ..., and $x_n = \{x_1\}$, then really this just reduces to $x_1 = \underbrace{\{\dots\{}_{n}x_1\underbrace{\}\dots\}}_{n}$ which just reduces to $x_1 = \Omega$ as we know that $\Omega = \{\Omega\}$. Similarly, graphwise we can see that if we picture an infinitely descending chain starting off some root $x_0$, we can "cut" off this root and instead picture the infinitely descending chain starting at $x_1$. Graphwise these two chains are identical, so really this is just a case of $x_1 = \{x_1\}$ once again.
With this in mind, whenever we face a nonwellfounded set, we can just reduce it to its components. If pure, it will just be $\Omega$, if composed with other (wellfounded) sets, it'll be a mix of $\Omega$ with other sets. (Say: $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ for the graph starting off a root node with two children, the left one without any outgoing edges and the right one with an edge onto itself.)
So, with all this in mind, what exactly would fail in the previous permutation model as a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ together with Aczel? That model seems to possess a unique purely selfcontaining set, in accord with the decoration uniqueness condition, and every other set seems to already be there? The wellfounded ones will be the same as usual only its (exterior) instances of $\emptyset_M$ are swapped to a $\{\emptyset\}_M$, the purely nonwellfounded can always be referred to the unique $\Omega = \emptyset_M$, and the mix of the two are the remnants with $\emptyset_M$ still within them (i.e., as an element), as we saw with the above example of $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ (externally: $\{\{\emptyset\}_M, \emptyset_M\}$).
Many thanks to any and all responses in helping clarify this issue and these doubts!

The main difference between the negation of Regularity and the anti-foundation axiom $\mathsf{AFA}$ is that the former states there is a non-well-founded set and the latter asserts every accessible pointed graph (a digraph with a designated root vertex) is isomorphic to a set. The latter is far stronger than the former, and the mere negation of Regularity even does not tell there is a set $x$ satisfying $x=\{x\}$.
You are correct about that an infinite descending chain takes one of the three forms you mentioned. What is not correct is that constructing an ill-founded set for three types of descending chain guarantees $\mathsf{AFA}$ holds. One example would be an ill-founded set $A$ isomorphic to the set of rationals: That is, $(A,\in)\cong (\mathbb{Q},<)$. Such a set exists by $\mathsf{AFA}$ (consider a graph over $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{*\}$, draw lines from $p$ and $q$ when $p<q$, $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}$ OR $p\in\mathbb{Q}$, $q=*$.) I do not see how to reduce $A$ to your cases.
Also, you claimed that there is a reduction procedure from accessible pointed graphs to their components. You may decompose a digraph into several parts, but how to recombine them? The usual set-theoretic operators are horrible for the recombination, since, for example, there is no way to recover an infinite linear order from these operators.

The construction of a model for $\mathsf{AFA}$ is already well-known. I attached an appropriate reference, but with a spoiler, since you seem not to want to see any hint.

 Aczel, Peter Non-well-founded sets. CSLI Lecture Notes, 14. Stanford University, Stanford, CA, 1988. xx+137 pp.


Thank you for the great answer! Guess I'll have to put some more thought into this whole matter ;) Quick question: By "designated root vertex" do you mean just any designated vertex or must it also verify the "there's a path from the root to any node on the digraph" property?

@Sho Good point, there must be a path from the root to other nodes.

Thank you! May I ask also (forgive me for being a bit slow in the understanding department) what exactly is it that fails with identification with $\Omega$ in the $(A, \in)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ example? I think we can agree that given a graph with $\omega$ nodes and edges $(n, n')$ iff $n < n'$ (what we would picture as an infinitely descending chain rooted at $0$) that $\Omega$ seems like a proper decoration. So what fails if instead of nodes in $\mathbb{N}$ we consider those in $\mathbb{Q}$? Is it the infinitely descending and ascending character, or...?

@Sho Your clarification only handles the accessible point graphs that are cycles or isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},>)$, so there is no room for other accessible point graphs. Set operators only add / adjoin vertices in a 'discrete' way so there is no clear way to create $A$ from your clarification.

Thank you once again for your quick and thoughtful response. I do agree and understand that the set operators at hand would make it so "creating" $A$ by the part recombination process you previously mentioned is not possible. My question was if —regardless of creation— the decoration $d(a) = \Omega$ for every node $a$ in $A$ would actually work as a decoration (as it seems to do with the $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ case) of if there's some other underlying issue at hand that makes it so it doesn't.
